# Using Node.js redis scanIterator correctly

Tags: javascript, redis

I am attempting to retrieve N keys at a time from my redis instance. I have N keys specified as `batchSize = 100` in this case. This code seems to loop infinitely, which indicates I'm not properly getting a cursor back. The output is infinitely recurring: `got a batch of 719 logs`. I have a total of 719 keys in my test db. So this should in theory, loop over `retrieveLogs` 8 times total with 7 batches of 100, and one batch of 19.

I can't dig up much documentation on how to properly use this, but here's my entire program. Is there something I am doing obviously wrong?

```js
/* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-syntax */
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const redisClient = createClient({ url: process.env.REDIS_URL });

redisClient.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Redis Client Error', err);
    throw new Error('Redis Client Error');
});

async function retrieveLogs(batchSize) {
    const logs = [];

    for await (const cursor of redisClient.scanIterator({
        MATCH: 'log:*',
        COUNT: batchSize,
    })) {
        const log = await redisClient.get(cursor);
        if (log) {
            logs.push(JSON.parse(log));
        }
        if (cursor === '0') {
            console.log('breaking');
            break;
        }
    }

    return logs;
}

async function main() {
    redisClient.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Redis Client Error', err);
        throw new Error('Redis Client Error');
    });

    await redisClient.connect();

    // Set the number of logs to retrieve and delete at a time
    const batchSize = 100;
    // Set a flag to indicate whether there are more logs to process
    let moreLogs = true;

    while (moreLogs) {
        // Retrieve a batch of logs from Redis
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
        const batch = await retrieveLogs(batchSize);

        if (batch.length === 0) {
            // If there are no logs, set the flag to false to exit the loop
            moreLogs = false;
            break;
        }
        console.log(`got a batch of ${batch.length} logs`);
    }

    await redisClient.disconnect();
}

main();
```

Comment: Did my answer below help you?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is your are collecting **all** the results on **each** call to `retrieveLogs()`, while your `while` loop in `main()` appears to be prepared to accept one chunk of items per invocation. This is not the case, as the async iterator `scanIterator()` returns already allows to consume all the `SCAN` results - hiding the complexity withing the async iterator itself.

So, to fix this you can either just drop the `while` loop inside `main()` or review the logic so that the result of the call to `scanIterator()` is iterated inside `main()`.

```js
// ...

await redisClient.connect();

// Retrieve a batch of logs from Redis

const batch = await retrieveLogs(batchSize);
console.log(`got a batch of ${batch.length} logs`);

// TODO: Use the batch

await redisClient.disconnect();

// ...
```

Also, `scanIterator()` returns keys and not a cursor, as the actual cursor is hidden in the async iterator implementation. So the short-circuit logic inside the async iteration should be removed and you may also want to rename that variable accordingly:

```js
for await (const key of redisClient.scanIterator({
    MATCH: 'log:*',
    COUNT: batchSize,
})) {
    const log = await redisClient.get(key);
    if (log) {
        logs.push(JSON.parse(log));
    }
}
```

And... the keys returned by `scanIterator()` are guaranteed to exist, so you *may* (depending on your parsing logic) even remove the extra truthy check for `log`.

Comment: Cobosi, If I get this correctly we are getting all the keys 1 by 1 (regarless of bacthsize) and the cursor is unknown.